# Why is superclass method calling overrided subclass method when the superclass method is the one specified to be called?

Tags: java, oop, hierarchy, superclass

Here i have the following Java code example, where i'm expecting "I'm A class" from A class method1(Integer arg) to be printed in main:

```
public class A {

    public void method1(String arg) {
                //some number passed, not important
        this.method1(1);
    }
    public void method1(int arg) {
        System.out.println("I'm A class");
    }
}
```

```
public class B extends A{

    @Override
    public void method1(String arg) {
        super.method1(arg);
    }
    @Override
    public void method1(int arg) {
        System.out.println("I'm B class");
    }
}
```

```
public class MainAB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
                //some string passed, not important
        b.method1("HI");
    }
}
```

So as i understand, the flow of the calls should be:
B class, method1("HI")  ->  A class, method1("HI")  ->  A class, method1(1)  -> print: "I'm A class"

But for some reason it goes from A class to B class and method1(1) from B class is being called, and "I'm B class" is printed.

Am i missing something? How can i solve this? Thanks

Comment: Why would it call `A.method1()` when you have a `B`? You would need a `super.method1(arg);` in `B.method1()` to invoke the `A.method1()` (if that's what you want).

Comment: Or maybe ((A)b).method1("HI");

Comment: @SamuelMarchant That is not how it works.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant Removing `this.` or `this()` has no such effect. `B extends A` : nothing can change that.

Comment: It would dependent haw you then call from outside the class in main.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant No it wouldn't. How you call something cannot change the inheritance. Your comments do not make sense.

Comment: @user207421 how something is called can be the only way you can access, but what you are saying would then mean there was no point in super or subclass 
inheritance  because only one version of method could ever be accessed. Second, calling non static classes inside static void main often has strange results! If you want non static methods to be operated shift all your calling code into the constructor of the main class and just use main to recursively start the class.

Comment: Really that's your trouble, you are trying to manipulate the scope of a non static class in a static context, to use super this properly you must be outside the static context.  Put a constructor in for MainAB and recursively call MainAB and a System.exit(0) to close it and initialise call everything from MainAB constructor. You will be able to use super this , (choose an internal or external hierarchy method call way to call code)  Using main method, the static context always throws everything into confusion. regular question once in while in forums, someone always is trying from main.

Comment: Initialise B in MainAB constructor, and test using this() and then super() as the first and only line of the constructor of B. And also ((A)bref).method1(str);.  Don't forget System.exit(0) at the end of main in MainAB

Comment: @SamuelMarchant It is you who is claiming that, not me: "`this()`" in the constructor of B would make B the superclass". This comment is not correct, and neither is your comment about removing `this.` from the method call, which accomplishes exactly nothing. I am unable to make any sense out of the rest of this. And who wants you to answer is irrelevant.

Comment: The critiqu'e from admin wants to answer this one, it is always the mess the static context from main causes when trying to run through complex non static code in main.  Until you are out of the static context of main when calling.....

Comment: @SamuelMarchant I can still make no sense of what you are saying, but, your claims about `this.` and `this()` being entirely incorrect, it is difficult to have any faith in anything else you post on this topic. Impossible, actually. And who wants you to answer the question remains irrelevant. If you really must answer the question, by all means do so: downvotes may ensue.

Comment: I finally got around to trying it with your code, and I must say "using super in A is a good sign of useless from the compiler" , A is not extended. The method in A would need a deliberate method in B to access because of the "peculiar" state of method overriding With method overloading causing "ambiguity". With inheritance it looks for the deepest class with the method name and loading arguments , and B has that, but B is this() and super cannot be coded into A. Normally that code gets a problem from static context (but obviously doesn't in your code this time) but I did it my way in main.

Comment: Sorry about this() about the constructor it's used to call another constructor in the same class with presets. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html    Also,  java reflection would be the only direct external way of accessing the A class method specifically.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant We know what `this()` does, thanks, that's how we know you're wrong. You're also wrong about using Reflection. The only way to access `A.method1(int)` specifically is via JNI.

Comment: That mislearned trouble about this() and constructors has been lurking a long time, anyhow, best practice would be to not have overridden overloads when writing a class to extend, then there will be no ambiguity of method names. Next one for me to play with that piece of code will be reflection to find if that weighs in as wrong  from what your saying. Also, Writing a class C and using.  super.  And super.super. to access is another possibility I'll try, these are very early java 1.3 sort of things when I was learning for the fun of it more than real over 15 years back.

Comment: Just another note on playing with that "ugliness of ambiguity" ,  the arguments to the methods per type have the same names also, then obtaining methods on an array with reflection has the same trouble identifying class A. If anything it all points to how to write code and " don't ever do this" (a bad practice) except when writing secure code that will need access by secure method access hops

Comment: ! , and another unspeakable toy to break with this code "casting to an abstract class with methods named method1( String and int.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant You haven't addressed most of the critique you've been given here. On the basis of what you have posted here you should be asking questions, not answering them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the flow of the calls should be: B class, method1("HI") -> A class, method1("HI") -> A class, method1(1) -> print: "I'm A class"

No, the correct flow is:

B class, method1("HI") -> A class, method("HI") -> B class method1(1) -> print: "I'am B class"

"I'am B class" - is printed because `method1(int arg)` is overridden in B class.

This is how Runtime Polymorphism work in Java, method invocation is decided based on the type of the object and not by the type of reference. The type of your object is B so the method1(int arg) of B is called.

You could prevent overriding `method1(int arg)` by making it final.

Answer (score 1):

Class *B* is inheriting the code from *A*.

If you hadn't overridden the *method1* method, then *"I'm A class"* would be printed.

Overriding is declaring that the inherited method from the super class should no longer be used.

Here is the *Java* tutorial on inheritance.
*[Inheritance (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Interfaces and Inheritance)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)*.